# Oversized image PDF Responsive Design

Tags: css

I have an iframe tag with a embedded pdf that is overflowing in the view of an iphone 5, how do i reduce the size of the pdf?

[image: Oversized PDF]

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" id="plugin" src="http://localhost:8888/work%20files/pdf/menu.pdf#view=FitH" type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="38">

<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" id="plugin" src="http://localhost:8888/work%20files/pdf/menu.pdf#view=FitH" type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="38">
```

Comment: Provide some code. If your width is set in pixels on `<iframe>`, try setting it in percentages.

Comment: You won't have any control over html and content rendered through an `iframe` but you can set it's `width` to `100%`, this should hide any overflow.